# Grails: Maintain n:m realtionship manually

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

Friends,

let's assume I have two Grails domains `Books` and `Authors`:

```
class Author {
    String name

    static hasMany = [book:Book]
}

class Book {
    String title

    static belongsTo = [author:Author]
}
```

This creates three tables in Mysql: `author`, `book` and `author_book`.

My assumption: The table `author_book` contains all relationships between authors and books, i.e. if book #23 belongs to author #42, the table `author_book` contains

```
|--------------------------|
|  book id   |  author id  |
|--------------------------|
|     23     |     42      |
|--------------------------|
```

That means that I'm able to maintain those relationship manually on database level by inserting the correct IDs into `author_books`.

Am I wrong? (Because I already filled my tables this way and nothing works as expected :-| )

Comment: Based on your domains above, I wouldn't expect the resulting schema to be what you described. When you have a belongsTo that has the property and not just the class, there should only be 2 tables with one of them storing the foreign key.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Didn't recognize the foreign key before. Now it works. Thanks